# Supervisor child vs plain spawn_link

Tags: process, erlang, spawn, erlang-supervisor

I have a hierarchy of processes called "monitor_node". Each of these monitor_nodes is supervised by one supervisor.

Now, each of these nodes may have a complex inner structure. Meaning, it may (or may not) have some subprocesses that are needed for it to operate properly. Example: process sending keep-alive messages. So far I have been using plain spawn_link to create these "internal" 
processes.

However, I have realized that spawning them in init function of monitor_node (which is being supervised) sometimes causes this function to fail (and therefore whole supervisor tree fails). My question is: would it be a good solution to attach these internal processes to supervisor tree? I am thinking about changing monitor_node to a supervisor that supervises it's internal processes.

My doubts are:

1. I would have to supervise quite significant number of very small processes. I am not sure if this is a good practice.
2. I may not know in advance that given "internal" process is a simple process or has some internal structure (also spawns other processes). If the latter is the case then I probably should attach these "inner-inner" processes to the supervisor tree.

I hope I have not confused you too much. Looking forward for an answer.

EDIT:

A very similar (if not the same) problem is discusses [here](http://www.trapexit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=54854) (3rd post). The solution given is pretty much the same as the one that I  GIVE CRAP ANSWERS gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Supervisors:

There is a trick here, which includes the use of two supervisors. Your tree goes like:

```
main_sup -> worker
main_sup -> attached_pool_sup

attached_pool_sup -> workers
```

main sup is `one_for_all`, so if the worker or the pool supervisor dies, then the tree is done for and killed off. The pool supervisor is a `simple_one_for_one` which are suitable for having hundreds or thousands of workers.

## Init:

Don't do too much work in your init callback. The supervisor will wait until the init completes and you can set a timeout (which you can increase in your case) if it takes longer than normal.

A trick is to quickly timeout (return with a timeout of 0 from init) and then handle additional setup in the `handle_info` timeout callback. That way you won't be stopping up the main supervisor. Beware of races here!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I assume that the `attached_pool_sup` would be responsible for supervising "inner" processes I have written about in my question?

Comment: Ok. So, in this case my `monitor_node:init` function would have to invoke `supervisor:start_child` on `attached_pool_sup` for each inner process. Am I right? If yes, wouldn't it complicate the `init` function too much again?